# When the Paladin hero power summons murlocs, what will vinecleaver summon?

Tags: hearthstone

Will [vinecleaver](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Vinecleaver) continue to summon silver hand recruits?

My question stems from the observation that acclaimed murlocadin decks such as [Kolento's](http://www.hearthstonetopdecks.com/decks/kolentos-midrange-murloc-paladin-top-100-legend-july-2017-season-40/) use this weapon, which according to the answers, would have no murloc synergy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the current hero power is independent of the Vinecleaver activation. If a priest steals a Vinecleaver and uses it, it will summon silver hand recruits, for example.